# Update number of products in icon cart woocommerce on IE 11

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, cross-browser

Hi i put the next code for add a numbers in the cart icon:

```
<p>
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a 
     class="cart-contents" title="&lt;?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?&gt;" 
     href="&lt;?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?&gt;"
  >
    <!--?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?--> - 
    <!--?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?-->
  </a>
</p>
```

When I update the products on the cart page, it is updated perfectly, except in Internet Explorer 11, how can I make Internet Explorer perform this update?

Comment: can you be more specifig? what display errors/issues generated in  Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Yes, when i update the products in the cart page on any browser the number in the cart icon is refresh but not in te Internet explorer 11, the code it´s grate for another browser but in IE 11 doesn´t work.